# How can i transform this table?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, transformation

I have a table with 300 rows and 200 columns and i need to transform it.
I add an image of the transformation with an example table.

[image: Example of transformation]

The table above is the original. The one below is the table after the transformation.

I was trying to solve it with excel and Pandas library of Python but i could not solve it.
Any ideas?

Comment: Try, `df.melt()`.   Look at that documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) after reading excel using pandas:

```
df = pd.read_excel('your_excel_path')
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='id', value_vars=['variable_1', 'variable_2'])
```

then write back to excel

```
df.to_excel('modified_excel.xlsx')
```